# Spring Batch : KafkaItemReader only works if consumer job is started before the producer job and when correct partitions are specified

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-batch, consumer

I have a simple Spring Batch job that reads from a Kafka Topic that has 3 partitions. I have the following observations/questions :

1. If the consumer job is started **after** messages were published to the topic, the consumer job waits infinitely for messages. The consumer only consumes messages if it is started first and then messages are produced to the topic. In the real world, I cannot wait for messages to be published and then start the consumer job. How do I tacklet this?
2. My topic has 4 partitions but the consumer only works if I provide partitions, 0,1 and 2 to the reader. If I provided partition 3 as well, the consumer waitis infinitley and somtimes also throws the following exception :

   ```
   Exception is......................... : 
   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms 
   expired before successfully committing the current consumed offsets
   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms 
   expired before successfully committing the current consumed offsets
   ```

**Consumer job configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(testFileWritingStep()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step testFileWritingStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("testFileWritingStep").<String, String>chunk(10)
                .reader(testKafkaItemReader()).writer(testFileWriter()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaItemReader<String, String> testKafkaItemReader() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        //not providing the actual broker hosts and ports on stackoverfow for security reasons..
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                "somebroker:someport,somebroker:someport,somebroker:someport,somebroker:someport");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "mygroup");
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "src/main/resources/conf/trust.jks");
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "pass");
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "src/main/resources/conf/loc.jks");
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "pass");
        props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "pass");

            
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        return new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<String, String>().partitions(0,1,2).consumerProperties(props)
                .name("myreader").saveState(true).topic("mytopic").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<String> testFileWriter() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(
                "I:/CK/data/output.dat"));
        writer.setAppendAllowed(false);
        writer.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
        DelimitedLineAggregator<String> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        writer.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        return writer;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. The reader should not wait infinitely, you can set a [timeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/kafka/KafkaItemReader.html#setPollTimeout-java.time.Duration-) after which the reader will return `null` and end the step. 2. Are you sure your kafka broker is still up in this case?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks for your comment. For 1)You are right. My reader timeout was very high. That said, still unable to understand why the reader consumes messages only if it is started before the messages are published. How can I ensure that the reader reads messages that are already available on the topic before it was started? For 2) I have a 4 broker setup. My topic has 4 partitions and 4 replicas. Even if one broker does go down, I would assume that reader would continue work with the other brokers. Ensuring that brokers never go down would be counterproductive?