# Spring Batch Kafka Consumer Job : Honor message groups across multiple JVM processes

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-batch, consumer

I have a simple [Spring Batch Kafka Consumer Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766011/spring-batch-kafkaitemreader-only-works-if-consumer-job-is-started-before-the) that reads data from a Kafka Topic and writes the data to a file.

I thought of spawning **5 instances** of my Kafka Consumer Job so that the job can complete faster. That is, I launched my program 5 times such that **5 consumer Jobs are started in their own JVM process**.

The immediate issue with this approach is that 5 processes will be writing to the same file. I tackled this issue by appending a unique process id to the file name. My updated writer bean is as follows :

```
private static final String UNIQUE_PROCESS_IDENTIFIER = System.currentTimeMillis();    

@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<String> testFileWriter() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(
            "I:/CK/data/output_from_consumer_"+UNIQUE_PROCESS_IDENTIFIER+".dat"));
    writer.setAppendAllowed(false);
    writer.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
    DelimitedLineAggregator<String> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
    writer.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
    return writer;
}
```

By appending the timestamp to the output file name, I am ensuring that each Consumer JVM Process writes to its own file.

When I finally launched 5 instances (JVM processes) of the same program, my expectation was that if one consumer job running in it's own JVM process reads a message from a partition,  other consumer jobs running in their own JVM process will not read the same message again from the same partition (since all the 5 Java processes will be using the same consumer group i.e **mygroup**)

However, I can see that each consumer job process (JVM) ends up reading all the messages. As a result, I now have 5 files, each containing the same contents. Example output file names with count of records in each file for better explanation :

```
output_from_consumer_1600530320385.dat -> 1 million records
output_from_consumer_1600530335555.dat -> 1 million reocrds
output_from_consumer_1900530335555.dat -> 1 million records
output_from_consumer_1900530335556.dat -> 1 million records
output_from_consumer_1900730334556.dat -> 1 million records

Total records: 5 million
```

**Question :** How can I configure my Spring Batch job such that even if multiple Java processes are launched with the consumer job, the  Java processes only read data not already read by consumers in the same group that are launched as separate Java processes?

This is my expected output (Just representational) :

```
output_from_consumer_1600530320385.dat -> 100,000 records
output_from_consumer_1600530335555.dat -> 200,000 records
output_from_consumer_1900530335555.dat -> 200,000 records
output_from_consumer_1900530335556.dat -> 400,000 records
output_from_consumer_1900730334556.dat -> 100,000 records 

Total records : 1 million
```

Comment: How many partitions does the Kafka topic contain for which you are trying to consume in parallel?

Comment: @ShreyJakhmola As mentioned in the linked question, I have 4 partitions for my topic. Each Java batch process is consuming data from all the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Running multiple instances of a Kafka consumer with the same consumer ID in the same group ID won't help you achieve parallelism.

Parallelism in Kafka consumers can be achieved by using multiple consumers each having a different consumer ID and the same consumer group ID. The consumer group is a grouping mechanism of multiple consumers under one group. Data is equally divided among all the consumers of a group, with no two consumers of a group receiving the same data.

Before assigning partitions to a consumer, Kafka would first check if there are any existing consumers with the given group-id.
When there are no existing consumers with the given group-id, it would assign all the partitions of that topic to this new consumer.
When there are two consumers already with the given group-id and a third consumer wants to consume with the same group-id. It would assign the partitions equally among all the three consumers. No two consumers of the same group-id would be assigned to the same partition.

Example
Suppose, there is a topic with 4 partitions and two consumers, `consumer-A` and `consumer-B` wants to consume from it with group-id `my-consumer-group` then Kafka will assign an equal number of partitions to each consumer that is 2 to `consumer-A` and `2 to the consumer-B`.

For your use case, since the Kafka topic contains 4 partitions, you can use 4 consumers having different consumer ID each and having the same group ID.

Comment: I am already aware of how consumer groups work. In my question, I clearly explained that I will be starting my program 5 times. This means that each instance of my program will attempt to read from all the partitions (As you can see, Spring Batch mandates that the KafkaItemReader be provided the partitions to read from). How do I ensure that when message 1 is read from partition 1 by consumer process 1, then consumer process 2 does not read the same message.  Spring batch KafkaItemReader is designed to always read from the beginning of the partition. Pleas do read about KafkaItemReader..

Comment: Why do you want to run 5 instances of the same application? If your answer is to consume fast and in parallel then the approach is wrong and that's not how parallelism or fast consumption in Kafka is achieved.

Comment: Also, with the Spring-batch 4.3 October release, the offset order property will be available for kafkaItemReader since it was not a feature, rather an issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3631).

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `KafkaItemReader`, you can specify which partition you want to read from:

```
KafkaItemReader reader = new KafkaItemReader(myConsumerProperties, "topic1", 0)
```

The above reader will read messages from partition `0` in `topic1`. So in your case, you can run jobs in parallel and configure each job to read message from a distinct topic (passing the topic/partition as job parameters for instance).

Comment: This means that the parallelism is limited by the number of physical topic partitions. What I am looking for is a way to spawn more consumers than the number of partitions. So if I have 4 partitions for example, I want to launch 8 consumers such that if one consumer reads a message, no other consumer in the same group will read the same message. Is there a way to achieve this in Spring Batch with Kafka?